# Best index for foreign key join plus range condition

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have several tables with 30+ million records that I need to perform paginated queries on with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    [DATE] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID, [DATE]) --Clustered
)
```

When dealing with data this size it's impossible to use `OFFSET FETCH` as sql server needs to first read through all the records 'till it reaches the 'page' I want.

So for each table I have a secondary 'index' table that I create which has a `ROWNUMBER` column which I create using `ROW_NUMBER()` to order the records:

```
CREATE TABLE A_Index (
    ROWNUMBER INT NOT NULL,
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    [DATE] DATETIME NOT NULL,
)
```

Using this index table we perform our paginated queries as such:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
INNER JOIN A_Index ON A.ID = A_Index.ID AND A.[DATE] = A_Index.[DATE]
WHERE A_Index.ROWNUMBER > 10000000 AND A_Index.ROWNUMBER <= 10100000
```

So my question is, what is the best index to create on this 'index' table? I've opted for CLUSTERED indexes but can't decide if the `ROWNUMBER` column should be the first column in the index or the last. I've looked at the query plan for both and got a mixed bag of results.

```
--Option 1: ROWNUMBER is the first column in the index:
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_ROWNUMBER ON A_Index(ROWNUMBER, ID, [DATE])

--Option 2: ROWNUMBER is the last column in the index:
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_ROWNUMBER ON A_Index(ID, [DATE], ROWNUMBER)
```

With option 1 I've seen needless, at least in my view, sorting of the ID and DATE columns. Whereas Option 2 usually takes longer to start returning results...

Thanks.

Comment: Ignoring the `A_Index` table, what is the ordering of `A` over which you wish to paginate? {ID, DATE} or {DATE, ID}?

Comment: ID, DATE. Same as the clustered primary key

Comment: Can you remember the last ID, DATE of the previous page (so you can start the next page after that), or you are limited to just skipping a number of rows from the beginning?

Comment: Unfortunately not. What if someone wants to jump to page 20 without visiting pages 1 through 19 first.

Comment: Allright, then you cannot use keyset pagination - you have to skip the first X rows. My hunch is that just skipping over the A's clustered index would be faster than the JOIN you are trying to implement.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but using OFFSET FETCH to skip 25 million rows takes over an hour because sql server will iterate over every single record before it starts returning results. This way I'm able to get results within a minute or two. If you're aware of any other method to skip records I would be interested in checking it out.

Comment: Frankly, I would just limit the users from skipping pages and implement keyset pagination. It looks highly unusual to me that the user would want to skip millions of rows essentially blindly. Users would rather use search in a scenario like that. But you know your users and I don't! ;)

Comment: We have a very special use case. This data is not feeding a UI :) We provide a data streaming service over http. Allowing people to perform concurrent multi-part downloads is more efficient than offering a single download start to finish. We're talking 100 million rows with 300 columns at times. Thanks for responding though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest two possible indices, and then discuss when each one might make more sense.  First index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON A_Index (ID, [DATE], ROWNUMBER);
```

This index would speed up the join back to your original table.  For each joined record (from both tables), the third index column `ROWNUMBER` could then be used to satisfy the range condition in your `WHERE` clause.  This works because `ROWNUMBER` would be sorted ascending, so SQL Server would only have to scan some range.

Second index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON A_Index (ROWNUMBER, ID, [DATE]);
```

This index first splits on `ROWNUMBER`, which would let SQL Server narrow down the index to only those records with matching row number values.  After this, it would have scan the index to make the join conditions.

The second index would make more sense if you expect your row number range to be relatively narrow, say a few dozen or hundred values only.  In this case, the second index would throw away almost all of the table, leaving behind only a few values to scan.

The first index would make more sense if you expect your row number range to be fairly large.  In this case, speeding up the join would take higher priority than scanning the row number values.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer Tim. I am indeed selecting a wide range (millions at a time). I'll wait to see if anyone else has any other insight on this before accepting your answer.